# How to disable full row selection in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I would like to have XP-like behavior on file selection, when only file names selected, instead of whole row or Name column:

> [image]

All I could find on the internet is how to change it to name-column-wide (like full row, but only name column). I'm searching how to make it XP-like exactly (see the screenshot). So far I have found at least one mention [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=76420&p=571457#p566218) that this is possible.

P.S. I don't know how other people like this "enhancement". To my opinion it does much more bad than good to ergonomics. Instead of aiming complexity we've got selecting complexity (when, for example, you can't start selecting a group of files starting from already selected one, cause explorer treats it as drag'n'drop. And that distracting hot tracking now.. I just can't work normally with all that!)

Comment: Several potential solutions...https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-disable-full-row-select-in-windows-7/862a337e-1eb5-4152-bba0-c54b70c94374

Comment: Doesn't the link you provide help you out? [Tweaking with Vishal](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-full-row-select-functionality-in-windows-vista-explorer/) has a solution but I have not tried it. Also [Winhelponline](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-full-row-select-explorer-windows-7/) has a solution but user's report that it has some [side effects](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/31918-full-row-selection-2.html#post713361)

Comment: Added clarification to the question